# Python3- Writing for loop output to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, python-imaging-library

```
import binascii
import struct
import os
from PIL import Image
anim_1 = Image.open(r"textures/water.png")
anim_1_txt = (r"textures/water_anim.txt")
print(anim_1.format)
print(anim_1.size)
print(anim_1.mode)

frame_rate = input("Enter a Frame Rate for water (default 2) - ")

anim_1_width = anim_1.size[0]
anim_1_length = anim_1.size[1]

anim_1_frame_length = ((anim_1_length)/(anim_1_width))

print ("Frame count is " + str(anim_1_frame_length))

with open (anim_1_txt, 'ab') as anim_:
    for x in range(0, int(anim_1_frame_length)):
            anim_.writelines(x)
print (("Writting Frame %d") % (x) + ('*') + (frame_rate))

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable "anim_.writelines(x)"
```

I have looked at the other questions on here that explain how to do this; everything I try doesn't seem to work, though. I was told to encode the string, but I can't figure out how to do that in the loop. Ive failed so many times with loops, i don't use them really. which makes coding really time consuming for me. I also need the loop to print each frame on a new line of the text file, for 
example:

```
1*2
2*2
2*3
...
```

Comment: Could you provide more information than *"doesn't seem to work"*? Error messages? Unexpected outputs? Be as specific as possible.

Comment: It isn't clear what data you want to write to the file. You only open one image file so where are these multiple frames that you want to write? And how do you want to write an image to a text file? Your code fails because `x` is a number and not a list of lines, but I can't tell you how to fix it without knowing what you want to do.

Comment: @jomrsharpe i did before you edited it. so you should have seen the error message. @ interjay anim_1_frame_length = ((anim_1_length)/(anim_1_width))

Comment: @interjay im writting the amount of frames to a file not the images themselves.

Comment: Please show the *full* error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is probably because you are giving an `int` to `writelines()`. 
Convert it to string.

```
for x in range(0, int(anim_1_frame_length)):
    anim_.writelines(str(x))
```

As for the second part of your question, you can use `\n` in your printed string. Since i m not sure which variable your "frame" is, i ll name it `my_frame` in code below.

```
for x in range(0, int(anim_1_frame_length)):
    anim_.writelines(str(x)) 
    # Use str(my_frame) if needed
    print('\n' + my_frame + '*' + my_frame)
```

Note that you have to use `str(my_frame)` instead if `my_frame` is not a string.

Comment: Thanks that was it:) i was trying print >> in lue of that. but this is what i needed. writelines didnt write more than one line tho.

Comment: .writelines did not work, it wrote "0*21*22*23*24*25*26*27*28*29*210*211*212*2..."
but i did 
    anim_.writelines((str(x)) + ('*') + (frame_rate))